# How can I make DictReader open a file with a semicolon as the field delimiter?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, bank

My csv file has the semicolon as delimiter. I can open it with

```
r = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
```

without any issues. The problem is that I want to open the file as a dict. The `csv.DictReader` class doesn't have the `delimiter` option.

My code:

```
import os
import csv
fields = ["Buchungstag", "Buchungstext", "Beguenstigter/Zahlungspflichtiger", "", "", "Betrag", "Verwendungszweck"]

with open("bank.csv") as infile, open("temp2.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

I tried opening the file and only loading certain fields, which works if I modify the file beforehand, replacing the `;` with `,` (I used notepad++ for this) – but I would like to skip this part and have the file directly opened.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) accept arbitrary arguments including `delimiter`, and pass them through to the underlying `reader` or `writer` object, as the documentation says:

> *class* `csv.DictReader`(…)
>
> All other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instance.

> *class* `csv.DictWriter`(…)
>
> Any other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying [`writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) instance.

Changing the relevant line in your code above to

```
    r = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=";")
```

should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks it worked, the problem was for me the order of the arbitrary arguments:
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, delimiter=";", extrasaction="ignore")
This works, but
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=";",  fields, extrasaction="ignore")
didn't work